# Proving that $x^{16} > 5$ when given a polynomial of degree $15$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I am unable to prove the following

> If $x^{15}-x^{13}+x^{11}-x^9+x^7-x^5+x^3-x = 7$ prove that $x^{16} > 15$.

Answer (score 7):

Note that your polynomial is a geometric series with first term $-x$, common ratio $-x^2$ so that it can be written as $$\frac{x(x^{16} - 1)}{x^2 + 1} = 7$$

So $$x^{16} = \frac{7(x^2 + 1)}{x} + 1$$

And now, all you need to do is show that $\frac{x^2 + 1}{x}  = x + \frac{1}{x} > 2$, which is not hard.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the left hand is equal to
$(x^3-x)(x^{16}-1)/(x^4-1)$; hence the equation will be transfer into:

$(x^{16}-1)=7(x^4-1)/(x^3-x)=7(x^2+1)/x$; notice that $(x^2+1)/x$ is graeter than 2, hence the right hand is greater than 7*2, therefor $x^{16}>15$.

Answer (score 2):

$ x^{14} - x^{12} + \ldots + x^2 -1 = \frac{7}{x}, $ I am considering $ x \neq 0 $ multiply both side by $ x^2 $ and add you get $ x^{16} = 1+ 7x + \frac{7}{x}. $ Take minimum of R.H.S.